# Setting a state in react but keep getting an error 'state' is assigned a value but never used no-unused-vars

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

i'm learning react.js state  and everytime im running this code i get error  'state' is assigned a value but never used  no-unused-vars

i tried to make class APP instead of function APP

```
import React from 'react';
import './App.css';
import Person from './Person/Person'


function App() {
  const state = {
   persons: [
  { name :'max', age : 28},
  { name:'manu', age : 29},
  { name:'adel', age : 30}
]
}
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1> Hello world</h1>
      <button> Switch name </button>
      <Person name= {this.state.persons[0].name} age= {this.state.persons[0].age} ></Person>
      <Person name= {this.state.persons[1].name}  age= {this.state.persons[1].age} >hello eslam </Person>
      <Person name= {this.state.persons[2].name}  age= {this.state.persons[2].age} ></Person>

    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 1):

The reason is this is a function. You need to use `state` instead of `this.state` for using it.

Answer (score 0):

You are not using the variable `state` you are instead using `this.state`.

---

Also if you want to use `state` of `react` in the function you may want to use `hooks`.

Here are links that can help you start with:

State & Lifecycle: https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html

Hooks State: https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html

Answer (score 0):

If you use variables and function in Functional component or in the tag `render(){...}` you don't need use `this`.

```
import React from 'react';
import './App.css';
import Person from './Person/Person';

function App() {
  const state = {
    persons: [
      { name: 'max', age: 28 },
      { name: 'manu', age: 29 },
      { name: 'adel', age: 30 }
    ]
  };

  return (
    <div className='App'>
      <h1> Hello world</h1>
      <button> Switch name </button>
      <Person
        name={state.persons[0].name}
        age={state.persons[0].age}
      ></Person>
      <Person name={state.persons[1].name} age={state.persons[1].age}>
        hello eslam{' '}
      </Person>
      <Person
        name={state.persons[2].name}
        age={state.persons[2].age}
      ></Person>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use a state like this

```
class Example extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      count: 0
    };
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <p>You clicked {this.state.count} times</p>
        <button onClick={() => this.setState({ count: this.state.count + 1 })}>
          Click me
        </button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

This is the base of using the states in react, although there is another way to use state in react, that is Hooks, here is an equivalent sample :

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';

function Example() {
  // Declare a new state variable, which we'll call "count"
  const [count, setCount] = useState(0);

  return (
    <div>
      <p>You clicked {count} times</p>
      <button onClick={() => setCount(count + 1)}>
        Click me
      </button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

For more information see:https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html